# Looping over a dataclass and fill values

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to fill a dataclass with values (not on initialization). I tried:

```
from random import randint
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class VData:
    var_a: list = None
    var_b: list = None
    var_c: list = None

X = VData

for var in VData.__dataclass_fields__:
    l = [randint(0, 10), randint(0,10)]
    X.__setattr__(X, var, l)
```

but get the error: `can't apply this __setattr__ to type object`. How do I correctly loop over the variables?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to use dataclass fields as class variables. I would then annotate them like `ClassVar[list]` if so.

Comment: also use `fields` instead of `x.__dataclass_fields__`, which is undocumented and might break somewhere in the future

Comment: Do you want to fill the class itself with values or an instance of the class?

Comment: I want to create multiple instances of this class with different start lists (set of coordinates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fields`. Avoid magic methods like `__setattr__` as a general rule.

```py
from random import randint
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields


@dataclass
class VData:
    var_a: list = None
    var_b: list = None
    var_c: list = None

X = VData()
xfilds = fields(VData)

for var in xfilds:
    l = [randint(0, 10), randint(0,10)]
    setattr(X, var.name, l)

# VData(var_a=[10, 2], var_b=[8, 9], var_c=[0, 6])
```

---

Note: `xfilds` is cached, `asdict` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `asdict` and `setattr` rather than their dunder equivalents.

```
from random import randint
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class VData:
    var_a: list = None
    var_b: list = None
    var_c: list = None
# you were missing a () which instantiates the object
inst = VData()

# Here, asdict gives you the dictionary form of a dataclass instance
# fields would work too as @rv.ketch pointed out
# if you don't have a need for the values of the dict
for var in asdict(inst):
    l = [randint(0, 10), randint(0,10)]
    setattr(inst, var, l)

print(inst)
```